# Is it possible to add authentication with devise if a model is already present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have added devise in my Gemfile and did bundle install..Now how can i give authentication to the sage which is created?

This is my controller sages.rb

```
class SagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def about
  end

  def new
    @sage = Sage.new
  end

  def create
    @sage= Sage.new(sage_params)
    if @sage.save
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for Joining'
      redirect_to '/thanks'
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Please fill the form Correctly'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @sage=Sage.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @sage = Sage.find(params[:sage])
    if @sage.update_attributes(sage_params)
      redirect_to '/thankss'
    else
      render 'new'
     end
end


  def resources

  end

  private
  def sage_params
    params.require(:sage).permit(:Name, :Email, :Address, :Number)
  end
end
```

This is my new.html.erb in which a sage is created

```
<div class="contact" style="padding: 50px; color: orange ">

  <%= form_for @sage do |f|  %>

      <div class="form-group" >
        <h3><%= f.label :Name%></h3>
        <%= f.text_field :Name %>
        <br/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" >
        <h3><%= f.label :Email%></h3>
        <%= f.email_field :Email %>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group" >
        <h3><%= f.label :Address%></h3>
        <%= f.text_field :Address %>
        <br/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" >
        <h3> <%= f.label :Number%></h3>
        <%= f.number_field :Number %>
        <br/>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <div class="submit" >
        <h2><%= f.submit 'SUBMIT'%></h2>
      </div>


   <% end %>

</div>
```

This is my routes.rb

```
  get '/thanks'=> 'users#thanks'
  get '/thankss'=>'users#thankss'
  get '/thanksss'=>'users#thanksss'
  resources :sages,only: [:new,:create,:edit, :update, :delete, :destroy]
  get '/sages/edit/:id'=>'sages#edit'
  get 'sages/home'=>'sages#home'
  get 'sages/about'=>'sages#about'
  get 'sages/resources'=>'sages#resources'
  get 'sages/delete/:id'=> 'sages#delete'
  delete 'sages/delete/:id'=> 'sages#destroy'
```

Comment: The best would be to follow the step by step guide from devise repository. Have you tried it ? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started

Comment: I just want to know do you want add devise for your slag model?

Answer (score 0):

Add following line into your controller,

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Or follow [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started).

Comment: its coming undefined method

Comment: Have needs to follow https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started to setup properly , before adding this line in to controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to add devise in your sage model for that type following command:

> rails generate devise Sage

before that make sure that you configure devise if not run this:

> rails generate devise:install

And at last run

> rake db:migrate

After this you do not need to your controller for sage CRUD, devise will do for you just use url "sages/sign_up"

For exact guide follow this  [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started)

Comment: Yes, you have but do you add devise to it, I think 'No', you just added 'Devise'  to  'gemfile' and run bundle only